# Set an attribute to a Rails record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a `User` model. I want to be able to set an arbitrary property for a user in one function.

```
> User["some_new_attribute"] = "test"  

# Error
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `some_new_attribute'
```

How can I assign an attribute named `some_new_attribute` to my User record?  I don't want to add a column in the DB for it, it's an attribute only used in one function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `attr_accessors`. Note that such fields will not be persisted in database via ActiveRecord.

```
Class User
  attr_accessor :some_new_attribute
end
```